# MySQL error 150 with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, sqlfiddle

I have this issue using foreign keys on MySQL. I am new in the language, and I have read a lot of the official documentation but got nothing in clear.

I also have checked other questions on this site about foreign keys but also didn't help me. I even copied a correct code and changed the names with my case and it kept giving me errors.

I am using SQL Fiddle to check my sintaxis. This is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Aparato(
Codigo SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Descripcion VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
TipoNombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
TipoCaracteristicas VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (TipoNombre) REFERENCES Tipo(Nombre),
FOREIGN KEY (TipoCaracteristicas) REFERENCES Tipo(Caracteristicas),
PRIMARY KEY (Codigo)
);

CREATE TABLE Tipo(
Nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Caracteristicas VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Nombre)
);
```

It's in Spanish, but I don't think that's relevant. I get this error, you can try it yourselves ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)):

```
Schema Creation Failed: Can't create table 'db_2_b9c14b.aparato' (errno: 150):
```

Even my databases teacher can't find where's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. SQL Fiddle won't allow reference to more than one PK **FROM THE SAME TABLE**. If you're going to reference several keys from the same table you must write just one FOREIGN KEY line, just like this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (TipoNombre,TipoCaracteristicas) REFERENCES Tipo(Nombre,Caracteristicas)
```

Also, the referenced table must be in the first place.

```
CREATE TABLE Tipo(
...
);

CREATE TABLE Aparato(
...
);
```

Thanks everyone for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your Caracteristicas like UNIQUE or adding like primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE Tipo(    
  Nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
  Caracteristicas VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (Nombre,Caracteristicas) 
);
```